Compress GIF image and append in formdata
In one of my .Net project, I want to compress image (jpg, jpeg, png, gif...) by javascript. Except GIF, compress is working fine. I tried different ways. But gif compress not working. Some process is working but after compress, animation not working just working as image but extension is .gif. And after compress I have to append that compress file in formdata and server side receive it in iFormFile.
